# How to use remote database in my node app

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, connection

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        port     :  3306,
        user     : 'id12642453_admin',
        password : 'mypassword',
        database : 'id12642453_teams_management'
    });
 console.log(pool)
exports.getConnection = function(callback) {

  pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if(!err) {`enter code here`
    //   return callback(err);
    console.log('connected')
    }
     callback(err, conn);
  });
};
```

My app is on local server and I want to use remote database, so I add these lines of code but its not working.

Comment: Well start with `host     : '127.0.0.1',` that will need to point to the other host using either a ip address or domain name

Comment: Then quite likely you will need to use a different `user :` and `password :` as they will also probebly be different

Comment: Then you will need to check if the `database :` name is also different or not

Comment: I make a database on 000webhosting, and these are valid credentials but its not working

Comment: If your app is on your local PC and the database is hosted on 000webhosting then `127.0.0.1`  **cannot be right** as `127.0.0.1` basically says **HERE on this PC** and you have told us the database is **over there on another PC**

Comment: You may also need to check that 000webhosting creates the mysql user account in a way that is allowed to connect from outside their domain

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239306/er-access-denied-error-when-i-try-to-connect-to-the-database-on-remote-server/60239515#60239515